# Javascript function pointers to object functions error throws error: TypeError: can't convert undefined to object

Tags: javascript

I am currently starting to read into javascript, and I am wondering why the following code throws an error:

```
a = [0,1,2,3];
x = a.pop;
x();
```

(Throws the error: `TypeError: can't convert undefined to object`).

While the following code works just fine:

```
x = console.log
x("hello");
```

What is the difference between these two? And is there any way I can those store a callable reference to `a.pop` in a variable?

Comment: `x` is a reference to the `a.pop` method. When calling `pop` method of an array (a function object in the arrays prototype), it needs an object as the context, but when you're calling the method without the context, the error is fired. `console.log` doesn't need the context, that's why it works "alone".

Comment: Out of curiosity: Is there any to provide the method with a context, for example like so `x.pop(a);` (This doesn't work, but is there something similar)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing more to add on what @Teemu said, he was faster to answer it, but here is a snippet where you can expand on his comment, the following snippet uses [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) function to add a context where `.pop()` should be applied to, also can use `.apply()`

```js
let a = [0,1,2,3];
const x = a.pop;

x.call(a);
console.log(a);

x.apply(a);
console.log(a);
```